# struts 2 use jqGrid to get row data before format

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery-plugin, struts2-jquery-grid

I want to get the jGrid data after it has been loaded.

Some columns have formatter but I want to get their original data before format.

The grid columns are :

```jsp
<sjg:gridColumn name="accountNo" formatter="linkBulider" />
<sjg:gridColumn name="amount" />
```

I use below js:

```js
var allRowsInGrid = $('#gridtable').jqGrid('getRowData');
for (i = 0; i < allRowsInGrid.length; i++) {
   //For accountNo I get the formmated value 
   allRowsInGrid[i].accountNo;
   //The amount is ok as it is unformated
   allRowsInGrid[i].amount;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Amethods) `getRowData` doesn't return the actual data from the grid.

> Returns an array with data of the requested `id = rowid`. The returned
>   array is of type `name:value`, where the name is a name from `colModel`
>   and the value from the associated column in that row. It returns an
>   empty array if the `rowid` can not be found.
>
> 1. **Do not use this method when you are editing the row or cell. This will return the cell content and not the actuall value of the input
>      element.**
> 2. **The performance of this method becomes an issue. Do not use
>      this method in the body of “for” and “when”. (When calling this
>      method, it will calculates the row datas one time.)**
>
> If the `rowid` is
>   not set the method return all the data from the grid in array

Once you used a [custom `formatter`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) option to format a cell content, you need an option to unformat the data.

> The question is: What to do if we use a custom `formatter` function and
>   want to to have the original value back if we use editing or methods
>   `getRowData` and `getCell`?
>
> The answer is: You can use your own custom `unformatter` function to do
>   that. This function can be used in `colModel`.

At this point you might check if the `sjg:gridColumn` could be set an attribute to define `unformat` function. Unfortunately, you can't do it according to TLD.

However, you can modify the grid after it's loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#gridtable").jqGrid('setColProp', 'accountNo',{
    unformat: unformatFunc
  }).trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

Comment: The `unformat` is what I've was looking for, thanks!